# Handling SEO on Isomorphic React

Tags: express, reactjs, seo, react-router, isomorphic-javascript

i'm using React & Node JS for building universal apps (). I'm also using react-helmet as library to handle page title, meta, description, etc.
But i have some trouble when loading content dynamically using ajax, google crawler cannot fetch my site correctly because content will be loaded dynamically. Any suggestion to tackle this problem?
Thank you!

Comment: Have you ever heard about server-side-rendering ?

Comment: yeah, already using server-side-rendering @FurkanO
since i need to fetch data first from API service, so it will run asynchronously.

Comment: If you are doing SSR, you shouldn't have a problem with SEO since everypage is rendered on the server. I am not sure if you are doing so. SSR means your first page fetches the data on the server.  Does your application  do so ?

Comment: hmm, im fetching the data on redux's action. so it will be fetching on the client side right? so, i need to move all data fetching on server? @FurkanO

Comment: Definetely, you should take a look at  repos with SSR on github to get started.

Comment: Hmm, do u have any great references to apply SSR?

Comment: This repo implements server-side-rendering github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example

Comment: Okay, will look on it. Thank you @FurkanO

Comment: http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ServerRendering.html here is also a great place.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar situation but with backend as django, but I think which backend you use doesnt matter.

First of let me get to the basics, the google bots dont actually wait for your ajax calls to get completed. If you want to test it out register your page  at google webmaster tools and try fetch as google, you will see how your page is seen by bots(mine was just empty page with loading icon), so since calls dont complete, not data and page is empty, which is **bad** for SEO ,as bots read text.

So what you need to do, is try server side rendering. This you can do in 2 ways either you [prerender.io](https://prerender.io/) or create templates on backend which are loaded when the page is called for the first time, after which your single page app kicks in.

If you use prerender its paid but pre-render internally uses phantom.js which you are you can directly use. But it did not work out really well for me so I went with creating templates on the backend. **So the bots or the user when come to page for first time(or first entry) the page is served from backend else front end.**

Feel free to ask in case in any questions :)

Comment: ah okay, thank you for the suggestion. Can you explain me more detail about the template on backend side?

Comment: yup.. the template which you create from react code ,just copy the created html from the inspect element and create a html file on the backend. I am assuming you need data in html(which you are getting from your API); that you can fetch from db(or call api) and pass it from the view to the template.